# Using In Operator in SharePoint 2010 Caml Query

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

I am using the IN Operator in SharePoint 2010 CAML query to get my desired set of results, however, the filter criteria doesn't seem to work and returns all records instead of the filtered set.

Here's how my SharePoint List is laid out; the text in bracket shows the actual column name:

```
Department (Title)     Approver (Approver)
------------------    --------------------
Department 1            Bob
Department 2            Mike
Department 1            John
Department 3            Peter
```

Here's how my code looks like (EDITED, THIS WORKS!!):

```
string camlQuery = @"<View><Query><Where>
                    <In>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Values> 
                            <Value Type='Text'>Department 1</Value>
                        </Values> 
                    </In> 
                    </Where></Query></View>";

string siteUrl = "http://mysharepointsite/sitename";

ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
List _oList = _clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

CamlQuery _camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
_camlQuery.ViewXml = camlQuery;

ListItemCollection listItemCollection = _oList.GetItems(_camlQuery);

_clientContext.Load(listItemCollection);

_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

return listItemCollection;
```

It should ideally return Bob and John, but it returns all 4 approvers.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If the value of the field does match the filter value exactly and you have only a single filter value, why don't you use simply the Eq operator instead of In? Or is it only a simplified example of a complex solution?

Comment: Hi pholpar, you're right it's just a simplified example of a complex solution. There might be multiple Value tags similar to how we generally use IN operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your `string _camlQuery` variable that is declared at the top, when creating the `CamlQuery _camlQuery = new CamlQuery();`

So you are using your undeclared `camlQuery` here `_camlQuery.ViewXml = camlQuery;`

Edit:

In SharePoint CSOM the root element for `CamlQuery.ViewXml` property is `<View>`.

So changing your query to be

```
string camlQuery = @"<View>
                     <Query>
                     <Where>
                    <In>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Values> 
                            <Value Type='Text'>Department 1</Value>
                        </Values> 
                    </In> 
                    </Where>
                    </Query>
                    </View>";
```

Comment: I assume that is only a typo, should be 'string camlQuery'. Otherwise it should be a compile-time error (double declaration of _camlQuery + undeclared camlQuery).

Comment: Hi Robban, sorry it was a typo. Please see updated code. I have also tried with <View> but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Did you try adding the <Query></Query> around the <Where> element?

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick! Thank you so much Robban!! You saved my day! :D

Comment: how to achieve the similar kind of results for the items whose ID ranges from 100 to 200 using IN operator ? can you please help with the query ?